# Worklight JSON store load method not populating search fields

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am working on the below example.

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/JSONStoreAPIBasicsProject.zip

When I add the data locally by using the 'Add Data' button, when the data gets displayed at the top contains name & age as search fields. Perfect.

[image]

But when I load the data from the adaptor with the button "Load Data from Adaptor' option. I don't see the search fields getting displayed in the output.

[image]

What could be the reason & will it have any effect on the searching capabilities ?

Thanks..Johnson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot confirm this. After playing with adding data and loading data from the adapter, I clicked on "Find all" and it produced the following table. As can be seen, all data is there.

In any case, you can confirm all data is loading by looking at the response. The table is filled using data from it. It looks like JavaScript/HTML error rather than anything related to JSONStore.

Provide steps to reproduce it exactly.

[image]

Comment: Idan, here is the problem. Sorry for not including the complete details. In the example, the adaptor provides the hardcoded data as below                      [{name: 'carlos', age: 100}, {name: 'tim', age: 99}] ;   In my example, I am getting these data from the DB. Now the data I am getting is in the format         {"name":"hi","age":32} . name has double quotes. This could be the problem ? Any idea how to resolve it ? Thanks

Comment: this could be an issue with column name case(Upper and Lower) in DB ?

Comment: Try and see if that's indeed the issue

Comment: Its indeed the issue. By default, the column names in db2 are created in upper case. I created a new table with lower case column names, it started working. Thank you!!